# latlng cannot be null - a position is required(React Native)

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-maps

I'm having the problem when runnig `react-native run-android`. Unless building on iOS is sucessfull but that on Android would not work. I use Animation UI, so can I realize that?

> latlng cannot be null - a position is required

My code is below:

```
  render() {
    const interpolations = this.props.places.map((marker, index) => {
      const inputRange = [
        (index - 1) * CARD_WIDTH,
        index * CARD_WIDTH,
        ((index + 1) * CARD_WIDTH),
      ];
      const scale = this.animation.interpolate({
        inputRange,
        outputRange: [1, 2.5, 1],
        extrapolate: "clamp",
      });
      const opacity = this.animation.interpolate({
        inputRange,
        outputRange: [0.35, 1, 0.35],
        extrapolate: "clamp",
      });
      return { scale, opacity };
    });

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <MapView
          provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
          ref={map => this.map = map}
          region={{
            latitude: this.state.coords.latitude,
            longitude: this.state.coords.longitude,
            latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
            longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
          }}
          style={styles.container}
        >
          {this.props.places.map((marker, index) => {
            const scaleStyle = {
              transform: [
                {
                  scale: interpolations[index].scale,
                },
              ],
            };
            const opacityStyle = {
              opacity: interpolations[index].opacity,
            };
            return (
              <MapView.Marker key={index} coordinate={marker.coordinate}>
                <Animated.View style={[styles.markerWrap, opacityStyle]}>
                  <Animated.View style={[styles.ring, scaleStyle]} />
                  <View style={styles.marker} />
                </Animated.View>
              </MapView.Marker>
            );
          })}
        </MapView>
       }
```

And I added `android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` on AndroidManifest also.

Comment: Do you have values in `marker.coordinate` ? lat long ?

Comment: I have `marker.cordinate`! sorry for late